# should questions regarding ubuntu and its derivatives be asked here?

Tags: discussion, ubuntu

it feels like `unix & linux` site is more related to unix OSes. Such as *BSD , Solaris etc.

Additionally, some less "user friendly" Linux OSes, can safely find home here. Such as debian, slackware, linux from scratch etc.

What is more there is another SE site for ubuntu questions! that is [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).

Sure I do see some questions getting migrated over to `askubuntu` , but some questions of the type  "my sound does not work in unity" that are still found on here seem only to flood this SE site, which in turn make it more difficult to dig info on other OSes since ubuntu questions inevitably climb to the top of search results.

So shouldn't some measure be taken to move the vast majority of `/ubuntu` tagged questions over there?

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I keep forgetting to search meta like the public site for dups.

Answer (score 7):

No! Ubuntu is just another variant of Linux, which is a Unix like operating system so they are very much welcomed either here or on AskUbuntu. There is a certain amount of overlap with many of the technical Stack Exchange sites, and this is perfectly acceptable.

We get a fair share of questions that could easily been asked on ServerFault, SuperUser, StackOverflow, or AskUbuntu. So long as the questions meet the guidelines of an SE site and are [on-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then they're welcomed additions to Unix & Linux.

Comment: With the exception of questions that pertain to Ubuntu-specific issues, like PPAs or Mir and those types of things...

Comment: @jasonwryan Questions about installing programs from PPAs or building packages to upload them to PPAs are on-topic here. It's only questions about the Ubuntu project that are not about using an Ubuntu system, such as questions about Launchpad accounts, that are off-topic here.

Comment: @Gilles: fair enough, I thought PPAs were an Ubuntu thing...

Comment: @jasonwryan They are, but being about Ubuntu doesn't make it off-topic. Ubuntu is a unix variant.

Comment: @Gilles: this makes no sense to me, if PPAs and Mir are on-topic here, then there seems little reason not to merge the sites.

Comment: @jasonwryan The sites cater to different audiences. On [ubuntu.se] there are people who use Ubuntu and don't care that it's part of a larger family. Here there are people who might use Ubuntu but just like they'd use Fedora or FreeBSD. Given how much larger the AU traffic is compared with U&L, if the sites were merged, we'd be drowned in AU.

Comment: @Gilles agreed about the drowning part; that is why I had assumed that Ubuntu-specific questions should be migrated (and, fwiw, the majority of those I flag are).

Comment: @Gilles while I agree that questions are on topic here (and I should have clarified this in the question), I still believe that the clarity of the site is reduced and the answer fails to address this issue. surely, ubuntu questions are on topic here, but if a large topic as `ubuntu` can get a SE site of its own, it becomes organisationally more convinient to address ubuntu questions there.

Comment: On the other hand, I pretty much would prefer to "unify" AskUbuntu and even SuperUser here. Two many places overlapping in my personal opinion.